# WPF application Process is high and it shows the wpfgfx_v400.dllMilResource_SendCommandBitmapSource+0x5f60

Tags: wpf

In my application there is one process which show the highest process. my application build in wpf. wpfgfx_v400.dllMilResource_SendCommandBitmapSource+0x5f60 this process takes 15-20 % CPU usege if user not doing anything and in application there is no any process. plesae help me

Answer (score 0):

SendCommandBitmapSource is called by UpdateBitmapSourceResource so it seems like you have a BitmapSource somwhere ethier downloading or updating (perhaps in a loop). So it seems your UI seems to be rendering somthing contiuously.